# Using IIS to show Bokeh dashboard

Tags: python, iis, bokeh

I am new to Internet Information Services for Windows. I have a *Bokeh* dashboard ready and I can serve it using the terminal and the command

```
bokeh serve app_myapp/ --port 5200 --allow-websocket-origin=my_IP_address
```

In IIS, I have set up the *Host Name* (xx.yyy.com) and the *Port* (80), and the *Physical Address* is `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\some_blank_htm_file`
Currently `xx.yyy.com`  shows my blank file, but I don't know how to connect serving my bokeh dashboard with IIS settings.
I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to use IIS as a reverse proxy. IIS is not a reverse proxy by default, so we have to add some modules and then start the configuration. These are all the steps I took:

1. Install the *URL Rewrite* package from the *Downloads* section on the IIS website.
2. Install the *ARR* (application request routing) module from the *Downloads* section on the IIS website.
3. In IIS, under sites, add a new website and set the *Host Name* to your FQDN. Also, Choose a Site Name and a Physical Path (I think it doesn't matter what.) and click OK.
4. In the left pane, double-click on the website you created. In the modules, double-click on *URL Rewrite*, then click on *Add Rule(s)*, choose *Reverse Proxy* and click *OK*. Then in the new window type ***127.0.0.1:my_bokeh_port*** and hit *OK*.
5. From the left pane, double-click on the main tree node with your server name on it, and from the modules, double-click on *Application Request Routing Cache*. In the right pane, choose *Enable proxy*, and set *HTTP version* to *Pass through*.
6. Use [this guide](https://docs.microfocus.com/itom/SiteScope:2018.05/Integrate/int_IIS_reverseProxy) to set *Server Farms*. Honestly, I'm not really sure if this step is necessary, but since I had done it before some of the former steps I just mentioned, I thought it might be.
7. Close and restart IIS.
8. Now, if you go to your website in your browser, you will probably see your address (for example *x.y.'com'*) change to *x.y.'com'/app_myapp*. If you can also see your dashboard, then that's all. If not, however, it means that your firewall is blocking the *WebSocket connection*.  You can use [this guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mandi/2014/11/03/how-to-create-a-windows-firewall-inbound-rule/) to allow a *TCP* connection to your *Bokeh port*.
9. Hopefully, now you can refresh and see your dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to show the bokeh dashboard when you use xx.yyy.com address?

In my opinion, the most easily way is using the IIS url rewrite  to achieve your requirement.

You could install it from this [url](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Then you could redirect all the request to the port 5200 by using below config setting.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Reverse Proxy to webmail" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:5200/{R:1}" />
        </rule>

    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

More detials about how to use reverse proxy, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing).

Comment: That's right, I wanted to show my dashboard in xx.yyy.com. Thank you @brando-zhang. unfortunately, I couldn't edit the config setting, but your answer helped me a lot.